# Complexity of the language of all TMs $M$ such that $L(M)$ is decidable

Tags: computability, turing-machines, semi-decidability

Let $$R = \{\langle M \rangle \mid L(M) \text{ is decidable}\}.$$ Is $R$ recursively enumerable or co-recursively enumerable?

Comment: What did you try? This might be a job for the Rice-Shapiro theorem, or some careful m-reductions.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? The answer to this question seems to be immediate from material that you've almost certainly been taught. We're happy to help with conceptual questions but just solving homework-style exercises for you is unlikely to really help you.

Comment: A language $L$ is decidable if $L = L(M)$ for some Turing machine $M$. Does this help?

Comment: A language $L$ is recognizable if and only if there is a TM $M$ for which $L=L(M)$. There are languages (like the acceptance language $A_{TM}$) which are not decidable but are recognizable.

Comment: This really depends on your definition of $L(M)$. I'm not sure there is a standard definition. For me $L(M)$ is only well-defined if $M$ always halts.

Comment: @kanjim What is the definition of $L(M)$ that you use?

Answer (score 1):

This set is not r.e. nor co-r.e., in fact [it's complete at the 3rd level of the arithmetic hierarchy](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/97943/37257) ($\Sigma^0_3$-complete). This is shown in Soare's textbook.